# MySQL Workbench will not let root connect Linux debian based

Tags: linux, mysql-workbench

There are thousands of people having this problem as I have seen checking the Internet which confirms it definitively it is a vicious bug from MySQL workbench.

This is a fresh Kali installation and mysql server comes installed by default, now named MariaDB. So when nothing has been assigned, root has an empty password as shown here:

[image]

So, then I install mysql-workbench like this:

apt-get install mysql-workbench and when I try to log  in, it says it won't let me in.
The error message is this one:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

HOWEVER:
I can connect from the terminal without a problem:

```
root@kali:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 32
Server version: 10.1.22-MariaDB- Debian 9.0
```

So this proves that root does have the right to access and that the password is correct which answers to questions 3 and 4.

I can verify there is a connection from localhost on 3306

```
root@kali:~# netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
root@kali:~#
```

which answers to questions 1 and 2.

This question has been going on since 2011 and yet there is not a single approved answer anywhere.

thanks

UPDATE

I can log in as another user, but not as root, so I can't do a lot of  things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some tests using a kali image. It's using mariadb , but is the same software. I've seen that new versions of MySQL Server are using unix_socket plugin for authentication. All I've done, is to remove this authentication for user root and connection with is available. I've done an alternative user with all privileges grant as a backup and connection user: if there's a mistake, you can't connect with root user in any manner!

Here is the link to a video showing all the process. It works for me!

https://youtu.be/qCsEQBsJqrI

Best luck

Miquel

Answer (score 0):

The answer was for me to use another computer that had Ubuntu instead of Kali linux installed.

Kali has a sort of a version of mysql server called mariaDB (what is that for a name!) and, of course, it has apache2 installed. For whatever the reason, this would only give me hell when trying to log on as root in mysqlworkbench.

However, when I installed a fresh ubuntu on another computer, it had nothing preinstalled (other than silly apps for kids and games) so I installed mysqlserver and note that I say mysqlserver as Kali WILL NOT let you download it, it will only allow you to download mariaDB, (which is preinstalled also) so you never actually get a chance to enter a password.

After installing mysqlserver I went for apache2 and I had to install it too because it is not in ubuntu.

Then I just installed mysqlworkbench using the expected line

sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

and then I could log on without an issue as root.

I did not have to do anything like apt-get update etc. Just apt-get install and run the apps.

So, the conclusion is that Kali in having a weird version of mysqlserver installed, which does not have a password, will only make your life hell trying to log as root both in mysqlworkbench and phpmyadmin, and maybe this has something to do with the fact that in Kali, you can only run the OS as root.

I have seen videos where a guy does install phpmyadmin in Kali and logs as root without a problem, but following his words ad-litteram would not give me same results. So I am only stating what worked for me, and this does not mean that someone will never be able to do it with Kali linux.